# How can we ensure security and integrity of data stored in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Since MongoDB lacks support of transactions how one can ensure consistency of data stored in MongoDB database?

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing concepts here. Transactions are related to atomicity and guarantee that multiple operations are either executed as a whole or not at all.

[Consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(database_systems)), however is (simplified) the guarantee that after each successful transaction or operation applied, the database is in a a valid, usable state.

## An example

> **Note** This example is simplified for the sake of understandability.

Often people say that you can not use MongoDB for financial operations such as account balancing, since it lacks transactions. They could not be farer from the truth.

Take a simple example of two users, each with an account:

```
{
  _id:"act1",
  owner: "Foo Bar"
},
{
  _id: "act2",
  owner: "Bar Baz"
}
```

And now, we have a collection we call "transfers". Each of our accounts get $100.00 from an outside source:

```
db.transfers.insert({from:"Scroogey", to:"act1", amount: 100.00, date: new ISODate()})
db.transfers.insert({from:"Scroogey", to:"act2", amount: 100.00 , date: new ISODate()}})
```

Now, how do we get the balance of our two accounts? Say Foo Bar wants to check his balance. We have to do an aggregation for that:

```
db.transfers.aggregate([
  { $match:{ $or:[ { from:"act1" },{ to:"act1" } ]}},
  { $sort:{ date:1 }},
  { $group:{
    _id:"act1",
    balance:{
      $sum:{
        $cond:[
          { $eq: [ "$to", "act1" ] },
          "$amount",
          {$multiply:["$amount",-1]}
        ]}
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Which gives us the correct value when run against `transfers`:

```
{ "_id" : "act1", "balance" : 100 }
```

So far, so good. So how does this relate to atomicity and consistency?

> [In MongoDB, a write operation is atomic on the level of a single document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents within a single document.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#atomicity-and-transactions)

So if we insert a document into the `transfers` collection, we achieve what we want: atomic transfers from and to accounts. Say *Foo Bar* wants to send *Bar Baz* $20.25:

```
db.transfers.insert({from:"act1",to:"act2", amount: 20.25, date: new ISODate()})
```

Atomic and consistent. Now, if we run our aggregation again, we get the correct result:

```
{ "_id" : "act1", "balance" : 79.75 }
```

If *Bar Baz* checks his account

```
db.transfers.aggregate([
  { $match:{ $or:[ { from:"act2" },{ to:"act2" } ]}},
  { $sort:{ date:1 }},
  { $group:{
    _id:"act2",
    balance:{
      $sum:{
        $cond:[
          { $eq: [ "$to", "act2" ] },
          "$amount",
          {$multiply:["$amount",-1]}
        ]}
      }
    }
  }
])
```

he sees the correct value, too:

```
{ "_id" : "act2", "balance" : 120.25 }
```

We have an atomic system to do account balancing without transactions! And still we have a log of all transfers from and to an account *which you need anyway*. We just use it differently.

## There is another way to do it

There is a way to achieve multi-document atomicity *from the applications point of view*, called [Two-Phase-Commits](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/).

Basically, it is an extension of the above. You'd have a transaction collection, in which pending operations are documented. Only if all operations are done successful, the transaction is marked as committed. There are various rollback scenarios. This is definetly more work than doing it like documented above, and should only be considered in case the data model can not be designed for the according use case. That would be the case when dealing with legacy systems, for example, in which you want to add features which would rely on transactions.

Basically you move the transaction logic from the DBMS to the application. This is not necessarily as disadvantage, since control over the various stages of a transaction which is supposed to be committed is much more granular.

## Conclusion

As we have seen, there are not transactions. With careful data modeling and a bit of knowledge about the inner workings and tools provided by MongoDB, there is hardly any use case that can not be implemented with MongoDB. It might not be the best tool for any use case, however, and you should choose your persistence system carefully.

If you really need transactions, use the Two-Phase-Commit approach.

Comment: This answer does not address the concern of the original question. In terms of  your example, what the OP is asking for is - when we update the bank account balances, can we guarantee they are always correct on both ends, i.e. the receiver will have $100 more and the sender $100 less, or if the txn fails, neither receiver nor sender will have their balance changed? THAT is what is being asked for and - let's be straight here - that is what MongoDB CANNOT guarantee. No bank will handle balances by endlessly aggregating.

Comment: @nepdev Have you actually read my example. Yes, the balance is guaranteed to be correct. And as for aggregations: How do you think interbank transactions are done?

Answer (score 2):

By-and-large, you can't. Mongo offers atomic actions per document ie a single document will be successfully written or rolled back. There is no way (as of v3.2) to ensure a set of documents will be all written or all rolled back. Document self-consistentcy can be built into the JSON written. Coming from a relational point of view, think of it like a widely denormalised DB with READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level. Even with the same structure, values types can be ingested differently. The value `2.0` and `"2.0"` are not the same, neither are `"FooBar"` and `"FoObAr"`.

V3.2 introduces [document validation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document-validation/) so you now have some guarantee that some parts of some documents have a certain structure. The very nature of schema-dynamic DBMS, however, means it is possible to insert JSON that reads like a cake recipe into a collection called "SharePrice." Good specs and code reviews are tools to address this.

All software sits in a niche. MongoDB as well, as do Oracle, SQL Server and the rest. With each DBMS, you gain a little and lose a little. Understanding and balance is the key, I believe.

Some further thoughts [at this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130668/36809).

Comment: I dare to object, slightly. With careful data modeling leveraging the fact that document operations are atomic, most use cases can be covered by documenting states or transitions at a certain points in time. As you have stated in one of your answers, there is always the possibility of a 2pc. So in general and by large, I'd say it is relatively easy to be atomic for most use cases. Just not as straightforward as with other DBMS.